# Excel VBA: Lock cells without protecting the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an add-in that sends and retrieves data from a database in order for this data to be used by our analysts. 
To prevent changes made to existing data points I want to lock the cells containing this data. Initially, I did this by locking the range of the data and protecting the workbook, since otherwise the locking does not work. However, protecting the workbook also removes/limits a lot of functionality for the end-user, such as creating graphs, the auto fill function, changing the format etc. Since these and other functionalities are needed for the end-user, I cannot protect the workbook. Still, I want to lock the cell containing the data points.

So my question is, is it possible to lock the cells in a dynamic range (I have macros detecting the correct end column and end row of the data points) without protecting the workbook? If so, how? If not, would it be possible to detect changes in the dynamic range and show a messagebox that changes are not allowed in this specific cell/range and revert back to the old value of the cell? If so, how?

I have seen a few posts asking a similar question, but these were either not answered or the answer was not satisfying for my case (e.g. a macro implemented in the VBA project of the workbook instead of the VBA project of the add-in).

Thanks in advance for your answer(s)!

Kind regards,
Robbert

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked=False
```

Then Lock your range which you don't want to be edited using:

```
Range("A1:A4").Cells.Locked=True
```

Then protect the sheet

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
```

This will only protect the contents that are `Locked` and still allow you to change values in the rest of the sheet and insert/delete charts. You may have to change extra settings with Protect. [More details can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)

Comment: This seems to solve almost all the issues I had with locking and protecting! Except for one, which is being able to use Home -> Fill -> Series/Justify etc. If I am correct this is not an extra setting for the Protect function, so what should I do to make this functionality available for the end-user?

Comment: @robbertvdh: If your functionality is very specific, you can create VBA code to cover your situation and lock the sheet `UserInterfaceOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to protect the `Workbook`, only the `Worksheet`.

To protect/unprotect a sheet via VBA, use Worksheet-methods `protect` resp. `unprotect` (you can apply a password).

To prevent a range to be modified, you have to set it's `locked`-property to True *and* protect the sheet (all cells have the propery `locked` set by default).

Be aware that, if a Range is locked and the worksheet is protected, you cannot modifiy the Range via VBA. If you want to do so, use the unprotect method at the top of the code (but don't forget to protect the sheet again when you're done). As an alternative, you can call `protect` with parameter `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`, but unfortunately Excel doesn't save this property. So if you save an Excel file where a worksheet is protected with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` and reopen it, the sheet is protected also for VBA.